# jQuery. Выпадающие списки. Один открывается другой закрываться должен

Tags: jquery, select, список

Как сделать, чтобы при выпавшем списке, если нажать на другой выбор, предыдущий закрывался, а нажатый, соответственно, открывался?

```js
$('.selbut').click(function() {
  $(this).children().children().slideToggle();
  var li = $(this).children().children();

  $(li).click(function() {
    var cur = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span').text(cur);

  });
});
```

```css
.selbut {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selbut ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.selbut {
  display: block;
}
.sel {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}
.sel li {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="selbut"><span>Выбор</span>
        <ul class="sel">
          <li>350x2000</li>
          <li>380x2000</li>
          <li>500x2000</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="selbut"><span>Выбор</span>
        <ul class="sel">
          <li>350x2000</li>
          <li>380x2000</li>
          <li>500x2000</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно присваивать открытому элементу специальный класс, например, `open`.
И при нажатии проверять есть ли такой класс. И если есть, и он не приписан нажимаемому элементу - закрывать все.

Вот примерно так (изменения внесены только в JS):

```js
$('.selbut').click(function() {
  if ($('.open').length) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $('.open li').slideToggle();
      $('.open').removeClass('open');
    }
  }
  $(this).children().children().slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');

});
$('.selbut li').click(function() {
  var cur = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span').text(cur);

});
```

```css
.selbut {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selbut ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.selbut {
  display: block;
}
.sel {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}
.sel li {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="selbut"><span>Выбор</span>
        <ul class="sel">
          <li>350x2000</li>
          <li>380x2000</li>
          <li>500x2000</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="selbut"><span>Выбор</span>
        <ul class="sel">
          <li>350x2000</li>
          <li>380x2000</li>
          <li>500x2000</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Уточните, пожалуйста, про $('.open').length В документации написано, что возвращает кол-во элементов. Это и есть проверка есть элемент или нет? Вернет true или false ?

Comment: Да, это проверка на наличие эдемента. Возвращает int - кол-во найденных элементов. По науке должно быть `if ($('.open').length>0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Еще попытался сделать закрытие списка через некоторое время (5 сек). Но кажется, что после второго клика закрытие то вовремя, то быстрее происходит.

```js
$('.selbut').click(function () {


    if ($('.open').length){


        if(!$(this).hasClass('open')){

            $('.open li').slideToggle(150);
            $('.open').removeClass('open');
        }
    }

    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(150);
    $(this).toggleClass('open');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.open li').slideUp(150);
        $('.open').removeClass('open');
    },5000);

});

    $('.selbut li').click(function () {
        var cur = $(this).text();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('span').text(cur);
    });
```

```css
.selbut {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selbut ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.selbut {
  display: block;
}
.sel {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}
.sel li {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="selbut"><span>Выбор</span>
        <ul class="sel">
          <li>350x2000</li>
          <li>380x2000</li>
          <li>500x2000</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="selbut"><span>Выбор</span>
        <ul class="sel">
          <li>350x2000</li>
          <li>380x2000</li>
          <li>500x2000</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```